# Using marshal vb.net Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net

It says marshal cannot be used, because it's protection level or the variable is been used before and it's been assigned to another value.

```
//code:
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
Dim int As Integer = 0
Public WithEvents Browser As WebBrowser
Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As Int32) As UShort

#Region "Using Proxy"
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function InternetSetOption(ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal lpdwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

Public Structure Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
    Public dwAccessType As Integer
    Public proxy As IntPtr
    Public proxyBypass As IntPtr
End Structure

Public Sub UseProxy(ByVal strProxy As String)
    Const INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY As Integer = 38
    Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY As Integer = 3

    Dim struct_IPI As Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
    Dim Marshal
    struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY
    struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy)
    struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local")

    Dim intptrStruct As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, True)

    Dim iReturn As Boolean = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))
End Sub
#End Region
```

Comment: just an important sidenote : interop is somewhat like an emergency-solution ... it should'nt be used for actual software since it has to be hardwired to machine-code and machine-code function signatures in particular, not to mention specific versions of them ... plus : you need to lookup and translate these signatures yourself (!!). Create a C++ / CLR library, import and use it within VB.NET, thats far less likely to break after a windows update and much more reliable. Marshalling is even worse and will only get you into trouble. WINAPI should only be used within native applications.

Answer (score 2):

`Marshal` is a reserved word; you cannot give a variable this name. Remove the `Dim Marshal` statement.